# Regex - select $ only when two conditions are met

Tags: regex

Conditions:

- it has to be between `<tag>` and `</tag>`
- between those tags, it has to have both `<b>` and `{1}`

Placement of `<b>` and `{1}` is random (but it's always between 2 tags).

If conditions are met, select only `<b>`.

I'm spending half day for that, and can't get it working, haha. Working on regex101.

This is example:

```
<tag><b>{1}test</tag> 
<tag><b>test</tag>
```

As far as my knowledge goes, the rough concept is:

```
(?! ( (condition1)|(condition2) ) (select word) )
```

Meaning both condition1 and condition2 have to be met to select (select word). Is there something wrong..?

EDIT: Practical sample, from game files:

```
<Entry>
      <DefaultText>&lt;line-height=100%&gt;{0}% Damage and Healing, {1} &lt;link="glossary://GlossaryEntry_Fortitude"&gt;&lt;b&gt;Fortitude&lt;/b&gt;&lt;space=0.7em&gt;&lt;#f9d968&gt;&lt;sprite="Inline" name="cs_fortitude" tint=1&gt;&lt;/color&gt;&lt;/link&gt;&lt;/line-height&gt;</DefaultText>

</Entry>
```

Comment: {1} has to be in front of the test?

Comment: Placement of <b> and {1} is random (but it's always between 2 tags) - this regex is for finding entries of game text entries (there is large amount, Pillars of Eternity)

Comment: test is some random string right ?

Comment: Your second example string shouldn't be matched right?

Comment: Exactly, it's missing one conditional, {1}

Comment: And yes, test is placeholder, practically it will be any of texts in game

Comment: These are literal examples? Meaning, except for the text “test” everything else stays identical? Because otherwise it looks like you need an HTML parser, not regex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1968

Comment: It was placeholder, added now to original post a sample straight from game files.

Comment: Also, some entries don't have {/d}, hence the 2 conditionals for regex

Comment: Yeah, don’t use regex for this. It’s the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: What do you suggest then? Mind you, I'm not really tech savvy when it comes to codes

Comment: What programming language do you know? Does the whole file start with something like `<?xml version="1.0" ... ?>`?

Comment: As mentioned, use an HTML (or XML) parser. Every modern programming language has at least one library for that.

Comment: What do you want to do once you have selected `&lt;b&gt;`?

Comment: @namelessone perhaps you should edit your open post with: `Placement of <b> and {1} is random` as per your comment. Seems to be quite important here.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte it's XML. For your second question, just delete (which could be done by replacing selection to nothingness)

Comment: And what programming language do you know?

Comment: None I'm afraid. I'm just helping modder with gui mod for game.

Comment: Can you give the desired match for your provided example?

Comment: `<tag>` is `<DefaultText>` or `<Entry>`?

Comment: I guess it can be any of them, they both cover the text

Comment: @JacobBoertjes since the <b> (&lt;b&gt; in this example) is between tags (either textdefault or entry) and this text has both <b> and {any number}, it should select only &lt;b&gt;

Comment: @namelessone can you please try [<tag>(?:.*\{1}.*<b>.*|.*<b>.*\{1}).*<\/tag>](https://regex101.com/r/rEx9xJ/4) ?

Comment: Ok, this will work: https://regex101.com/r/797VwV/1

Comment: Awesome, this works great <3 @CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: @UnbearableLightness tested, unfortunately it didn't select anything. Casimir's solution works. But thank you very much for trying!

Comment: Yeah it was for your initial test cases, was not adapted for the practical sample, yet :)  But @CasimiretHippolyte's solution is better.

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten to write `</DefaultText>` in the last line: https://regex101.com/r/797VwV/2/

Comment: `select $ only when two conditions are met` So, where is the dollar sign ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP admits to not knowing any programming. This is a programming site.

Answer (score 0):

Check on the next regex `<tag>(?=(?:(?!<\/?tag>).)*?<b>)(?=(?:(?!<\/?tag>).)*?\{1})(?:(?!<\/?tag>).)*<\/tag>`.

To try the regex online and get an explanation, please click [here](https://regex101.com/r/9lg8ks/2).